# How to fake HttpClient into a private field in Angular / Jasmine tests?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests, karma-jasmine

In my Angular 9 project I have this code to define a `HttpClient` in the `DataService`. The DataService is the most common service in the app, every other services extend it. More than 50 services. Because of this big number of services what extned the DataService, this is the reason why the HttpClinet is defined this way.

If I put the HttpClient creating into the `constructor()` then I need to create a new HttpClient in all the 50 services, and I want to avoid this.

The `private` is because I want to avoid direct using the HttpClient in the child services.

**data.service.ts**

```js
import { InjectorInstance } from 'src/app/app.module';

export class DataService<T> {
  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(model: T) {
    super(model);

    this.http = InjectorInstance.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);
  }

  // ...
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

export let InjectorInstance: Injector;

@NgModule({
  // ...
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    InjectorInstance = this.injector;
  }
}
```

Now I need to create tests on this service, and now I need to create a fake HttpClient.

I want to do something like this:

```js
describe('DataService', () => {
  let httpClientSpy: { get: jasmine.Spy };
  let service: DataService<any>;
  const model: any = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    httpClientSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get']);
    service = new DataService(model);
    service.http = httpClientSpy;
  });
});
```

But here I get `Property 'http' is private and only accessible within class 'DataService<T>'` error.

How can I create a fake HttpClient to this service?

Comment: I think you need to mock `InjectorInstance`'s `get` instead of mocking `HttpClient`.

Comment: @ngShravil.py could you show me a sample code how can I do this?

Comment: I just updated the question with app module codes

Comment: Using polymorphism for service is bad. I don't know why you need to do it when you already have dependency injection with Angular.

Comment: Is the answer here of any help? About mocking the 'get' call of Injector. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444904/how-to-mock-a-injected-service-in-a-function-with-injector

Comment: I think so it helped...

Answer (score 2):

First extending classes will make it harder for you to test everything.
Each class that extends some functionality needs to duplicate all tests related to this functionality if you just create separate service for handling it you only need to create unit test for that service.

Consider injecting DataService instead of extending it. Then you can test it like this:

```js
export class DataService<T> {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient;
  ) {
  }

  // path can be hardcoded or handled in diffrent way just example
  get(path): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get(path)
      // ..format server data
      .pipe(
        map((data) => ({ ...data, wasProcessed: true })),
        shareReplay(1),
      );

  }
}
```

```js
import { TestBed, inject, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController,
} from '@angular/common/http/testing';

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule, // angular testing module that provides mocking for http connections
    ],
    // Add here declaration of your services or components and use inject to get to them in tests
    providers: [DataService]
  });
})

it('should request data from server', fakeAsync(inject([
  HttpTestingController,
  DataService,
], (
  httpMock: HttpTestingController, // this part will help us in testing
  service: DataService, // tested service
) => {
  // Arrange
  let result: any = 'no one expects spanish inquisition';
  const path = '{apiEndpoint}/home';
  const data = { some: 'data' };
  const expected = { ...data, wasProcessed: true }; // or whatever your data service does with returned data

  // Act
  service.get(path)
    // we just care about what we get in the end
    .subscribe((data) => result = data)

  // Assert
  httpMock.expectOne(path).flush(data);
  tick();

  expect(result).toEqual(expected); // after processing server response
  // check if there arent any other not handled requests
  httpMock.verify();
})));
```

You can find more example how to test diffrent stuff in angular [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/xcaliber-unit-testing-workshop?file=unit-tests%2Fexamples.spec.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Consider my comment:

> I think you need to mock `InjectorInstance`'s get instead of mocking `HttpClient`.

As you have initialized `InjectorInstance` in **app.module.ts** file, it becomes little difficult to mock it in components. So, if you directly do the dependency injection of `injector` in `DataService` class, it will be easier to mock it.

You'l have to do the following changes:

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  // ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**data.service.ts**

```js
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class DataService<T> {

  private http: HttpClient;

  constructor(model: T, 
              private injector: Injector) {
    super(model);
    this.http = this.injector.get<HttpClient>(HttpClient);
  }

  // ...
}
```

**data.service.spec.ts**

```js
describe('DataService', () => {
  let service: DataService;
  const model: any = {};
  let injectorSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Injector', ['get']);

  beforeEach(() => {
    injectorSpy.get.and.returnValue(of(HttpClient));
    service = new DataService(model, injectorSpy);
  })

  it('equals', () => {
    expect(1).toBe(1); // This is just to pass the test, you can put your own expect here.
  })
});
```

With these changes, at least you will not get any errors.

Comment: My problem is with this solution is the `constructor(model: T, private injector: Injector) { }` part... If I put it here just because of tests, then I need to update all of my services which created like this: `export MyCustomService extends DataService<MyCustomInterface> { constructor() { super(MyCustomModel, InjecorInstance); } }`. And I don't want to complicate my services with extra parameters - only for tests.

Comment: Any `http` calls are happening in the constructor or it is simply getting initialized?

Comment: only initialization happening there

Comment: But with your code it will be difficult to mock it. May be with `TestBed` it's possible, but I am not aware of it.